# Android menu showAsAction icon too big

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-drawable, android-toolbar

I noticed the menu icon displays way too big when using `showAsAction="ifRoom"`. i noticed that the darker outline when long pressing on the icon is also bigger than the normal menu icon (three vertical dots). I am using a 72x72 icon as recommended by the android reference for bigger devices. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to include four different images to fit different screen sizes.

```
MDPI: 160 DPI 48x48 px
HDPI: 240 DPI 72x72 px
XHDPI: 320 DPI 96x96 px
XXHDPI: 640 DPI
```

I had this issue as well. If you are using a Toolbar within the layout you need to specify a tablet version of the layout.

**Toolbar Height**

```
Mobile Landscape: 48dp
Mobile Portrait: 56dp
Tablet/Desktop: 64dp
```

Setting the toolbar height to 64dp within the xlarge layout shoudl solve the issue.

Setting these attributes should help with the issue.